# How to change X, Y coordinates according to screen size or density?

Tags: android, multiscreen

I have some coordinates information with me, on these coordinates I am showing the views dynamically. As android devices comes in multiple resolution and density, so my view got messed in high or low resolution(which is not according to coordinates). 
I want to use my same coordinates with multiple screen sizes without messing my views. I read on android developer site that we can do it using density calculation but cant able to figure it out. Please help me to solve this problem I am really stuck at this point.

I am also attaching my code where I am adding views dynamically.

```
for (int layoutIndex = 0; layoutIndex < layoutSize; layoutIndex++) {
        SubMenuItems coorObj = submenuCoordinateList.get(layoutIndex);

        System.out.println("X coordinate= " + coorObj.xCoordinate.trim());
        System.out.println("Y coordinate= " + coorObj.yCoordinate.trim());

        subMenuLayout[layoutIndex] = new LinearLayout(this);
        subMenuImageView[layoutIndex] = new ImageView(this);
        subMenuResultView[layoutIndex] = new TextView(this);
        subMenuNameView[layoutIndex] = new TextView(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams nameParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                80, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layoutParams.leftMargin = Integer.parseInt(coorObj.xCoordinate
                .trim());
        layoutParams.topMargin = Integer.parseInt(coorObj.yCoordinate
                .trim());

        subMenuLayout[layoutIndex].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        subMenuNameView[layoutIndex].setLayoutParams(nameParams);

        subMenuNameView[layoutIndex].setTextSize(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
        subMenuResultView[layoutIndex].setTextSize(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);

        subMenuImageView[layoutIndex]
                .setImageResource(SubMenuItems.resSubMenuImages[layoutIndex]);
        subMenuNameView[layoutIndex]
                .setText(SubMenuItems.resSubMenuName[layoutIndex]);
        subMenuResultView[layoutIndex].setText(menuId + " Result");

        subMenuNameView[layoutIndex].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        subMenuResultView[layoutIndex].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        subMenuLayout[layoutIndex].addView(subMenuImageView[layoutIndex]);
        subMenuLayout[layoutIndex].addView(subMenuResultView[layoutIndex]);
        subMenuLayout[layoutIndex].addView(subMenuNameView[layoutIndex]);

        submenu_icons_layout.addView(subMenuLayout[layoutIndex],
                layoutIndex);
    }
```

Comment: If you want the same "location" on screen you just calculate your x, y with the density of the screen. This is what the dip or dp does in xml code. I suggest you don't use absolute coordinates on all the layout items because the density can be the same from one phone to another, but the shape and size of the screen changes from phone to phone.

Comment: @nininho How can I formulate or calculate my x,y coordinates with density? Can you please provide any example or code.

Comment: You can get the density of the screen this way: getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; then just multiply your x and y coordinates by the density

Comment: I have coordinates like this [{50,100}, {120,70}, {200, 200} ...], If i applied you trick it will be not proper.

Comment: This link may help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels , that whole page can help if you don't have worked with different densities before